# How to create directories/files on the local machine using Django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, blockchain

I'm working on a blockchain project where I'm implementing a wallet using Django. A user logs in and get's to generate an address. Now, I want to store the user's private key/public key pair in a file locally on the user's machine every time a user generates an address, and be able to read that file again in the next session (at the user's will). I'm doing this because the app itself is a supernode of the blockchain and all users are virtual nodes. All communication between users happen through the supernode, thus the wallet functionality isn't the core function of the app.

Everything is working perfectly except I can't find a way to create files locally on the client's machine. I've perused the Django documentation but I can't seem to find anything useful (maybe I'm not looking in the right place).

Is there a way I can achieve that?

Note: I'm trying as much as possible to avoid JavaScript, and I don't want users to download/upload files manually.

Comment: Django runs on your server, JavaScript runs on the client. It is `impossible` for Django/Python to create directories on the remote machine (unless you're doing some kind of hacking or using system tools and have access, I guess). The modules you mentioned in the other comment create stuff on the server, not the client.

Comment: @KostasMouratidis Ten months later I can assure you I was dumb and a good one at that.

Answer (score 0):

Saveing data/files on the clients machine is restricted but modern browser for good (security) reason.
However there are Cookies (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/http/sessions/) or html5 webstorage (https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: I've looked into the solutions you suggested, all of them are temporary. I found a way using `shelve` and `tempfile` modules, and I think they might suffice my need. Thank you.